# Randomise matching methodology R

Tags: r, random

I am looking to run a model that matches randomly matches 2 datasets (person and vacancy) based on matching characteristics of both datasets. 
A person can have a role type, location, other and the vacancies will be looking for these characteristics.

Current methodology is using a for loop to work through the vacancies, subset the person table based on the matching characteristics and randomly pick a person.

Rough outline of current code:

```
for (I 1:dim(Vacancy)){

     individual_vacancy = Vacancy[1]
     available_person <- person[...matchingconditionsfromindividualvacancy....andavailable=1]

     Vacancy$personid[I] = randomsampleofavailableperson

     person$Available[personid == randomsampleofavailableperson] = 0

}
```

This is very slow and computationally expensive due to the size of the dataset and from what I can assume is the looping and writing back to the original datasets.

Are there any methodologies for this kind of problem/ R packages I'd be able to take advantage of?

Edit: This is a 1:1 matching problem which is where the problem is occurring. i.e. 1 person must be allocated to one vacancy. The Available flag update ensures this at the moment.

Comment: Use `dplyr`, join the two datasets and then use `sample_frac()` or `sample_n()`.

Comment: I considered this but it doesn't account for the 1 to 1 matching nature of the problem. I.e. if you join on vacancy and person you could randomly allocate the same person to multiple vacancies

Comment: tricky to give more advice without a [mcve] to work with.